# Syntax error on incremental append with sqoop in putty

Tags: hdfs, sqoop

When I am trying an incremental append with sqoop in putty,it throws syntax error.

```
mysql> sqoop import --connect 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db' 
       --username retail_dba --password cloudera 
       --table sample --target-dir /Aravind1/sqoopdemo01 
       --check-column id --incremental append 
       --last-value 2 -m 1;
```

Error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'sqoop import --connect
>   'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db' --usernameretail_' at line 1"

I am trying to append into the file a new record inserted in the table "Sample" Can anyone help me out with the issue?

Thanks,
Aravind

Comment: This is sqoop command, should not be executed from mysql shell.

Comment: mysql cannot understand sqoop commands. You should run sqoop code on linux command line interface or make it shell script.